# Image does not go in database with file name only tmp name saved?

Tags: image, laravel, upload

i am new in laravel 5.1 when i upload image they goes to in folder but in database actual name don't saved. The database have name like: `C:\wamp\tmp\phpCA22.tmp`.

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: my controller code is `public function uploadImage(Request $request)
    {
       if($request->hasFile('image')){
           $destinationPath=public_path().'/images/';
           $file = $request->file('image');
           $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();
           $request->file('image')->move($destinationPath,$filename);
        }
        $inputs = $request->file('image');
        $users = Upload::create($inputs);
        return redirect('user/upload');
    }`

Comment: my view code is `{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'user/uploadImage','files'=>true, 'method'=>'post')) !!}
{!! Form::label('file','File') !!}
{!! Form::file('image') !!}
{!! Form::submit('Upload') !!}
{!! Form::open() !!}
`

Comment: Cool. Answered you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP is not revealing the code.

I am giving the general workarouod

**Step 1 :** 
If you get input file

```
if(Input::file())
{
//Your stuff here
}
```

**Step 2 :** Get the File's name

```
$image = Input::file('image');
$filename = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

**Note :**

1. Don't forget to have `multipart/form-data` in your form
2. Have the name of your image as `image`

**Update :**

Here's the update code that you'd require

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request) 
{
 if($request->hasFile('image'))
 { 
 $destinationPath=public_path().'/images/';
 $file = $request->file('image');
 $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();
 $request->file('image')->move($destinationPath,$filename);
 } 
 $inputs['filename'] =  $request->file('image'); 
 #$inputs['yourkey'] = 'yourdata';
 $users = Upload::create($inputs); 
 return redirect('user/upload'); 
 }
```

`$inputs` is the array. You should have the `filename` in the fillables in your model also make sure `filename` exists in your table

**Update 2 :**  As the OP gives the coloumn name

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request) 
{
 if($request->hasFile('image'))
 { 
 $destinationPath=public_path().'/images/';
 $file = $request->file('image');
 $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();
 $request->file('image')->move($destinationPath,$filename);
 } 
 $inputs['image'] =  $request->file('image'); 
 $users = Upload::create($inputs); 
 return redirect('user/upload'); 
 }
```

Comment: no it do not working if i follow this code then the image name not goes to database table..

Comment: You should change `$filename` to `$inputs['filename']`

Comment: I will update your entire coding, pls wait

Comment: ok sir thanx in advance..

Comment: Updated . If you see any issue in the code, pls do inform

Comment: sir name not goes to database. the database column  is blank.

Comment: Can you return the $inputs ?

Comment: when i check output after `$inputs['filename'] =  $request->file('image');`                 with    `dd($inputs['filename']` the out put show as `UploadedFile {#30 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "1.png"
  -mimeType: "image/png"
  -size: 97060
  -error: 0
}`

Comment: Çan you just do `$file = $request->file('image');
 $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName(); return $filename;`

Comment: after return $inputs the name of image is print on screen.

Comment: Cool, That's what we need.. Now here we go

Comment: What is in the fillable array in your model ? And what's the coloum name in the table

Comment: my model is `class Upload extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
     'image'
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = "uploads";
}
`  and in table name also `image`

Comment: You're done now..  `$inputs['image'] =  $request->file('image'); 
 $users = Upload::create($inputs);`

Comment: This should do the magic

Comment: sir again tmp name save in database this code...

Comment: Before create if you do `return $inputs['image'];` what's happening ?

Comment: same thing tmp path name show on browser  `C:\wamp\tmp\phpCECA.tmp`

Comment: If you do this `$file = $request->file('image'); $inputs['image']=$file->getClientOriginalName(); return $inputs['image'];`

Comment: image name printed on browser but when i implement it like `$file = $request->file('image'); 
            $inputs['image']=$file->getClientOriginalName(); 
            
            $request->file('image')->move($destinationPath,$inputs['image']);` then same problem occures

Comment: That's okay.. Can you do this and say what stores in db ?  `$file = $request->file('image'); $inputs['image']=$file->getClientOriginalName();  $users = Upload::create($inputs);`

Comment: thanx so much  Sulthan Allaudeen sir it doing work

Comment: You're welcome.. If this answer helped you. You shall accept it by clicking on the tick icon +1 for your effort ;)